# Unable to default omit when synchronize attributes are multiline in Ansible

Tags: ansible, syntax-error, runtime-error, default, rsync

Below Ansible works fine when `final_file_perm` is defined:

```
   - name: Copying from "{{ inventory_hostname }}" to this ansible server.
     synchronize:
       src: "{{ item }}"
       dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/tmpfiles/{{ Latest_Build_Number }}/"
       rsync_opts: "{{ final_file_perm | default(omit) }}"
       mode: pull
     with_items:
       - "{{ source_file.split() }}"
```

However, my requirement is to have multiple multiline `rsync_opts` on new line like below:

```
rsync_opts:
      - "--chmod=F0775"
      - "--chmod=D0775"
```

So I tried the following:

```
   - name: Copying from "{{ inventory_hostname }}" to this ansible server.
     synchronize:
       src: "{{ item }}"
       dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/tmpfiles/{{ Latest_Build_Number }}/"
       rsync_opts:
         - "{{ final_file_perm | default(omit) }}"
         - "{{ final_folder_perm | default(omit) }}"
       mode: pull
     with_items:
       - "{{ source_file.split() }}"
```

The above does not work and give me the following error:

```
TASK [Copying from "remhost" to this ansible server.] *********************
failed: [remhost] (item=/u/files/inst.zip) => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh=/usr/share/centrifydc/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null __omit_place_holder__6fd53eb1f5a7fbe7c6691ba6f3aada2e52378343 __omit_place_holder__6fd53eb1f5a7fbe7c6691ba6f3aada2e52378343 --out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L remuser@remhost:/u/files/inst.zip /web/playbooks/filecopy/tmpfiles/124/", "item": "/u/files/inst.zip", "msg": "Unexpected remote arg: remuser@remhost:/u/files/inst.zip\nrsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1344) [sender=3.1.2]\n", "rc": 1}
    to retry, use: --limit @/web/playbooks/filecopy/copyfiles.retry
```

As you can see ansible synchronize module is not liking `__omit_place_holder__6fd53eb1f5a7fbe7c6691ba6f3aada2e52378343` right after `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null`
I also tried the following:

```
   rsync_opts: [ '{{ final_file_perm | default(omit) }}', '{{ final_folder_perm | default(omit) }}' ]
```

But, I get similar error as shared above.

Note: this works fine when `final_file_perm` and `final_folder_perm` are defined. Errors only when they are undefined and I wish to omit them.

Can you please propose a solution where I can use `default(omit)` for attributes on multi newlines?

Answer (score 1):

Then you will want to build up the `rsync_opts` list conditionally, rather than having what amounts to `None` items *in* the list

```yaml
   - name: Copying from "{{ inventory_hostname }}" to this ansible server.
     synchronize:
       src: "{{ item }}"
       dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/tmpfiles/{{ Latest_Build_Number }}/"
       rsync_opts: "{{ my_rsync_opts }}"
       mode: pull
     with_items:
       - "{{ source_file.split() }}"
     vars:
       my_rsync_opts: >-
         {{ [] +
            ([final_file_perm] if final_file_perm|d("") else []) +
            ([final_folder_perm] if final_folder_perm|d("") else []) }}
```